# Bluetooth HFP on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, hfp

i am trying to connect my raspi with a BT-Headset with the build in bluetooth. it is working with pulseaudio 5.0 and bluez 5.23.
But the thing is it just supports A2DP. i want to use it as a real Headset so i Need HFP. I read that bluez 5 doesnt Support this Profile anymore and with pulseaudio 5 and bluez 5.23 it wont work.

Now i got a bluetoothdongle with my Headset and if i am using the bluetoothdongle instead the buildin Bluetooth it is working. i can record Sound. But i get a better Audio Output with the build in (with dongle it is lagging) . Maybe it is because the dongle uses the hfp Profile directly and therefore the Audio ouput isnt that good anymore.

So i was wondering if this is gonna work with every Bluetoothdongle which supports the HFP/HSP Profile.

And my other question is how does pulseaudio and bluez work together. and how would the BT-dongle would work with pulseaudio together? 
Bluez 4 supported hfp and hsp. pulseaudio 5 is backwards compatible so this would be an Option i think. does anyone has tried it?

thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a development question, I think it would fit better in OS support channels of "overflow" like superuser ?